# Attempting to run parallel tests with py.test and -n option is not working

Tags: pytest

I am attempting to run parallel tests with pytest in mac terminal, but when I use:

py.test -n NUM

I get the following error:

```
Alexs-MacBook-Pro:sauceTests alex$ py.test -n 3
usage: py.test [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: -n
  inifile: None
  rootdir: /Users/alex/PycharmProjects/sauceTests
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install a plugin for that:

```
pip install pytest-xdist
```